# Flat catalog in Magento 2.4.*

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, flat-catalog

Magento now uses ElasticSearch by default and the latter is the tested/recommended way to use Magento.

However, the Flat Catalog options are still in the config and the the core code that drives these features is still in place in Magento latest versions.

- Has anybody used Flat catalog recently?
- Is the flat feature still a thing for anybody?
- Is the feature scheduled to be removed at all?

Comment: So far we haven't used it in any of our new projects. That being said, if we look at the magento core, many of his functionnalities, especially, around database tables are relicates / deprecaqted of older versions that are not used anymore. Does magento plan to clean his code some day ? Can't tell but it would be great indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Magento no longer recommends the use of a flat catalog as a best practice. Continued use of this feature is known to cause performance degradation and other indexing issues.